# Ordered List Square Box Not Working as Planned

Tags: html, css

This picture explains the sitatuion:

http://demo.krsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/stack.jpg

First part of the pic is what I wanna do, the second part is what I have.

The html part is nothing more than:

```
<ol>
  <li> content <li>
</ol>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
ol {
    color: white;
    background-image: url(http://demo.krsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/pinksquare.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I've tried to move the gif box with the margins and paddings with negative numbers but without any success.

Also the whole alignment is messed up now...

Any help please?

Comment: please post *all* the relevant code. we cant debug pictures... but try to play with `line-height`, set it to `1em` or `0.5em` and see if you get better results. and dont float things. also consider using flexbox.

Comment: You should start a question by explaining what you are trying to achieve, not by chatting about your  background. Here a description would probably be that you are trying to make the item numbers of `ol` elements to appear in square boxes by using background images.

Comment: there's no need to be so rude and yet say nothing.

Pretty much the image is self explaining.

[link](http://demo.krsites.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/stack.jpg)

The first is what I'm aiming for and the second is what I have using the css I showed you.

The code is nothing more than :
`<ol>
<li> content </li>
</ol>`

Comment: The link may be self-explanatory, but it wasn't present in the body of your question until I edited it in. The thing about [SO] is that we like our questions to be self-contained as far as possible, so the *question* should be *in the question*. You're perhaps unable, at your current reputation, to add images to your questions, which means we need you to explain your question clearly and not just rely on the external link. This, and the advice above, isn't intended as hostility, just guidance for the future.

Comment: I coudn't get it to work with lists by any chance...not exactly how the customer designed so I had to use divs.

Here's the css:

`.boxes-texto .indice {
background: #ec008c;
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
text-align: center;
}

.boxes-texto div {
width: 24%;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
position: relative;
vertical-align: top;
}

.boxes-texto div p {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 17px;
color: #ec008c;
padding-left: 28px;
padding-right: 10px;
}`

It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to line up background-images with text, I'd suggest using CSS generated content to style the list-counter:

```css
ol,
li {
  /* removes the default counter: */
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol {
  /* optional, this restarts the counter for each <ol> element: */
  counter-reset: listCount;
}

li {
  /* incrementing the counter in each <li>: */
  counter-increment: listCount;
}

li::before {
  /* displaying the counter, the counter function takes a
     second argument if required, to set the counter's "type":
     counter(listCount, roman) for example: */
  content: counter(listCount);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(155,0,155,0.5);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> content </li>
  <li> content </li>
</ol>
```